# Registro de DNS

Tags: dns, cpanel

Acabo de contratar un servicio de hosting, y en el manual me enviaron instrucciones, pero me falta un paso mas...
Tengo estos servidores DNS...

- DNS1 dns1.dnshostingcotas.com IP1 200.58.160.102
- DNS2 dns2.dnshostingcotas.com IP2 200.58.160.102
- DNS3 dns3.dnshostingcotas.com IP3 200.58.160.169
- DNS4 dns4.dnshostingcotas.com IP4 200.58.160.169

Mi pregunta es, donde tengo que registrarlos en la parte de Dominios en el administrador cPanel 62.0.16
Podrían guiarme por favor...?

Answer (score 0):

1. En Cpanel
2. Addon Domains
3. En Create an Addon Domain
4. Ingresas el dominio completo
5. Si quieres crear una cuenta de ftp para ese dominio, chequeas Create an FTP ...
6. click en Add Domain

Listo, está hecho.

Ahora asegurate de ingresar esos dns en el panel del sitio donde registraste el dominio.

Solo la IP la pones en el panel de control del sitio en donde registraste el dominio. En los custom dns. Entonces, ve al sitio en el cual registraste el dominio. Logueate, busca el dominio y ve al panel de control del dominio. Allí pon las ips que tienes arriba, las urls no se usan.

Saludos,

Comment: Podría por favor ser mas específico...

Comment: Te puse el paso a paso, qué no es claro?

Comment: No veo donde poner el url y el ip...

Comment: Solo la IP la pones en el panel de control del sitio en donde registraste el dominio. En los custom dns. Entonces, ve al sitio en el cual registraste el dominio. Logueate, busca el dominio y ve al panel de control del dominio. Allí pon las ips que tienes arriba, las urls no se usan.